DC high current power supply with fast response time
I’m looking for a DC power supply that can do 100A at at least 24V but hopefully 60V.
The main issue I have is that all the supplies I am looking at seem to have response times in ms where I need to to at least pass a significant amount of its total current within 100us.  I have tried to use an inverter welder but it just seems not fast enough.
Is there any hope to buy a supply like this or is this something I have to make custom?

How long will the 100A current last, and how much voltage drop can you tolerate?

100A is about 1-5 ms tops at around 1-10hz tops.  Voltage drop can be down to about 20V to be safe

How much is the output voltage allowed to drop in the 100 us and, what length of time between consecutive 100 us pulse demands? If necessary draw a profile of what you need.

So would it be correct to say that you don't need a 100A power supply, but a 5A average power supply (5ms * 10Hz * 100A) that can output 5ms 100A current pulses, with maximum 4V voltage drop? In this case you could use a bunch of caps, or a small lead acid battery, kept topped by a power supply with about 5A output current...

Assuming: 5ms long, 100A current pulses, with a repetition rate of 10Hz, allowed voltage drop 4v.
\$ \frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{i}{C} \$
\$ dv = \frac{i}{C} dt \$
With C = 200 000µF, dt=5ms, i=100A, then dv=2.5V.
Average current: 100A x 5ms x 10Hz = 5A
So you could use a 150-200 000 µF capacitor bank, of suitable voltage rating, kept charged up by a power supply capable of 5A output current. If you use enough cheap snap-in capacitors in parallel, ESR should be adequate to reach your target voltage drop.
If you get a 60V 100A power supply (6kW) to use it with a duty cycle of 5%, then the remaining 95% of the time you are wasting your money. Capacitors will most likely be a lot cheaper.
I would recommend a constant current power supply to charge them, because most constant voltage supplies would have trouble telling the difference between the caps and a short circuit. You could use an AC-DC LED driver directly as an AC powered constant current source, but these will also have trouble charging the caps from 0V.
For example, starting from an off the shelf 60-70V 5A DC switchmode supply, you could use a constant current output buck converter to charge the caps. If this is driven by a voltage comparator with adjustable threshold, it will charge the caps up to the voltage you want, making it adjustable.
You will also need a way to discharge the caps (for example a switched resistor or lightbulb) and an indicator light to warn the user the caps are still charged.
Another option would be a lead acid battery, but the output voltage won't be adjustable.
